# How to correctly enlarge an image from within a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I'm using the following code to zoom/enlarge an image from within a table view. I would like it to enlarge out to full screen. the current problem is that when it enlarges it enlarges only within the table cell (and as a result is partially hidden beneath the next table cell) instead of the full view.

```
    -(void)zoomPhotoMethod :(id) sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);

    userSubmittedImageView = (UIImageView *)gesture.view;

    if (!isFullScreen) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            //save previous frame
            prevFrame = userSubmittedImageView.frame;

            UIView *popupImageViewForTableCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 320, 500)];

            [userSubmittedImageView setFrame:[popupImageViewForTableCell bounds]];


        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = TRUE;
        }];
        return;
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [userSubmittedImageView setFrame:prevFrame];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = FALSE;;
        }];
        return;
    }


}
```

updated code:

```
   -(void)zoomPhotoMethod :(id) sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);

    userSubmittedImageView = (UIImageView *)gesture.view;

    if (!isFullScreen) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            //save previous frame
            prevFrame = userSubmittedImageView.frame;


            newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];

            [self.view addSubview:newView];

            UIView *popupImageViewForTableCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 320, 500)];

            [userSubmittedImageView setFrame:[popupImageViewForTableCell bounds]];

            [newView addSubview:userSubmittedImageView];

            [userSubmittedImageView setFrame:[newView bounds]];

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = TRUE;
        }];
        return;
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

            [userSubmittedImageView setFrame:prevFrame];


            [newView setFrame:prevFrame];

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = FALSE;;
        }];
        return;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that you are still a subview of the tableview cell, so it's not going to be able to go outside of those bounds without being clipped.

To do what you want to do, you're going to have to:

1. Create a new UIImageView outside of your table view (add it as a subview outside of the tableview).
2. Set the image in the image view to the same image that you have in the tableview cell.
3. Start it at the same size and position as your tableview cell image.
4. Animate it up to where you want it.
5. When it's time to remove it, move it back down to the original tableview cell image.
6. Discard the imageview.

Comment: please check my updated code above. updated code - I tried what you said and it's almost working. the only problem is that the image doesnt return to its original place

Comment: This is because when you return it to it's original place you should do: `[userSubmittedImageView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, prevFrame.size.width, prevframe.size.height)];` because your userSubmittedImageView is *inside* the newView, so it's origin should be at (0,0)

Comment: Yes, @gWiz is correct here. Though the code seems way over complicated for what you're trying to do here. For instance, what's the point of the popupImageViewForTableCell view? It doesn't seem like it's used anywhere besides to get it's bounds, which you set the line before.

Comment: Also, when you're resetting your image to it's previous location, it's still a subview of the "newview" you made, it's not reset to the previous location in the view. You really need to make a new imageview, set the image into that, set it's location, and animate it up rather than doing this convoluted method to use the original view. Then when you're done, move it back down and discard that image view.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a copy of the image and place it outside the cell just above your original and animate this second image to full screen.

Another way would be to increase the tableView rowHeight and reload the section.